# How to use "seem" + noun

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between these two:

*1- It seems water.

   2- It seems to be water.*

Comment: Difference is that "it seems water" is wrong, you cannot use a noun directly after seem.

Comment: Thanks. So why don't you offer it as an answer?

Comment: @MorganFR: except that when we're talking about people, we often use a noun directly after *seems*. Google search finds tons of examples, for example: E.M. Forster, *A Room with a View*: "He seems a nice creature, and I think he has brains." It sounds completely wrong for inanimate objects, though.

Answer (score 0):

The second is correct, "it seems to be water".

The reason is that the verb seem means "give the impression of being something".

In English, "to make an *impression* of water", would imply that you are making a painting of water, or an imprint of water.  Technically you are giving the impression of **being** water, or **moving** like water or **sounding** like water.  Hence the use of the verb "to be" before the noun water.

Comment: And is _It seems water_ incorrect grammatically, to you?